# Is it possible to hide API operations in swagger when the viewer is not authenticated

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, swagger-ui

i am working on a spring-boot project where we use swagger for documentation of our API. So far so good. But it is requested to hide API operations for not authenticated viewers.

I tried several things to get this done. Including the steps in Chapter 7 of the Baeldung tutorial (https://www.baeldung.com/swagger-2-documentation-for-spring-rest-api)

But this gives me only the possibility to not try out the API operations as long as the viewer is not authenticated. The operations are visible in both cases (authenticated/not authenticated).
As said earlier this is not what i need. I need it to be hidden when not authenticated.

Is there any possibility to do so?

Thank you in advance.